# Where does a LIMIT apply in a UNION?

Tags: mysql, sql, limit, union

It is not clear to me where a `LIMIT` applies to a `UNION`
If I have:

```
SELECT * From table A  
where conditions  
UNION  
SELECT * From table B   
where conditions  
LIMIT 10
```

Does the LIMIT 10 apply to the **result** of the UNION? Or to the select of table B?
What I need is to apply to the result of the UNION

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html):

> To use an ORDER BY or LIMIT clause to sort or **limit the entire UNION result**, parenthesize the individual SELECT statements and place the ORDER BY or LIMIT after the last one. The following example uses both clauses:

```
(SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1)
UNION
(SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2)
ORDER BY a LIMIT 10;
```

**A statement without parentheses is equivalent to one parenthesized** as just shown.

---

In your case:

```
SELECT * From table A  
where conditions    
UNION --assuming the union is here
SELECT * From table B   
where conditions  
LIMIT 10
```

The limit will be applied to the **result** of the union.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the UNION operator? Anyway the LIMIT of 10 probably applies on the result of the UNION at least in the place you put it.